# How to access the MVC "action" from the current request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to retrieve the current routing action from a MVC request?

Cheers,

raj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, all route values are stored in [RouteData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routedata.aspx). If you want to know it in a view, you use:

```
<%= Html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] %>
```

If you are in a controller, you use:

```
string action = RouteData.Values["action"];
```

Am I answering your question?

Comment: But... Wouldn't you know what action has been requested inside a controller action? It's the action that is being executed.

Comment: Yes, of course :-) I wanted to originally mention it, but there could be a legitimate reason for it. For instance, an action can call some generic infrastructure utility function which may need to inspect it.